# VB code behind RedirectPermanent Not Working

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, redirect

Newbie question here. I'm redesigning an ASP.NET site to 4.0 and have a bunch of old URLs that I need to redirect. I'd like to do it in the code behind file instead of page-by-page basis. Can someone tell me why this isn't working?

```
Protected Sub Application_BeginRequest(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

If Request.FilePath = "/olddirectory/oldfile.aspx" Then
    Response.RedirectPermanent("index.aspx", True)
End If


End Sub
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your current redirect is trying to go to `/olddirectory/index.aspx` which will cause a 404 if it isn't there (you didn't specify the error).  If you change to

```
If Request.FilePath = "/olddirectory/oldfile.aspx" Then
    Response.RedirectPermanent("/index.aspx", True)
End If
```

It will redirect to a page called index.aspx in the root of your application.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I appreciate it. Most of the redirects are 404s but there are some 301s. Would those be approached differently? This code above is still generating a 404 error.